# Fetch data from twitter in r

Tags: r, twitter

Can you help me in fetching data from twitter its been days. Researched a lot cant solve this.

```
library(twitteR)  
library(ROAuth)  
library(RCurl)  
library(pacman)  
library(devtools)  
library(rjson)  
library(httr)

    consumerKey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"  
    consumerSecret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"  
    access_token <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"  
    access_secret <- "Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"



if (!require('pacman')) install.packages('pacman')
pacman::p_load(twitteR, ROAuth, RCurl)

options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file('CurlSSL', 'cacert.pem', package = 'RCurl')))

reqURL = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token'  
accessURL = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token'  
authURL = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize'

twitCred = OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey = consumerKey, consumerSecret = consumerSecret, requestURL = reqURL, accessURL = accessURL, authURL = authURL)
twitCred$handshake(cainfo = system.file('CurlSSL', 'cacert.pem', package = 'RCurl'))
```

It directs me to authorize and I key in  the code and press enter

The next step

```
setup_twitter_oauth(access_token,access_secret)
```

I get this error. How to solve this.

[1] "Using browser based authentication"

```
Error in init_oauth1.0(self$endpoint, self$app, permission =self$params$permission,  : Unauthorized (HTTP 401)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set up an app on Twitter (https://apps.twitter.com/)? This is how I got it working, you do the authorisation there which gives the relevant keys and then with twitteR it's as simple as

```
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key = consumer_key,
                consumer_secret = consumer_secret,
                access_token = access_token,
                access_secret = access_secret)
```

And then to retrieve a timeline:

```
userTimeline(user = "@BBCBreaking")
```

Comment: I have setup an app already however I think I am able to generate some tweets. Thanks!!